# Nextjs Logic enters Else, but does not return the desired output in browser

Tags: next.js

I am trying mplement a logic where, return vale will depent of the parameters passed in the browser URL.

But when I try to open http://localhost:3000/docs,
The logic should enter the else part, which it is not and showing 404

```
import React from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const docs = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const {params = []}  = router.query
    console.log(params)
    console.log(params.length)
    console.log("DEBUG-1")
    if (params.length == 2) {
        console.log("DEBUG-2")
        return(
            <p>
                Param 0 : {params[0]} <br></br>
                Param 1 : {params[1]}
            </p>
        );
    } else if (params.length == 1) {
        console.log("DEBUG-3")
        return(
            <p>
                Param 0 : {params[0]}
            </p>
        )
    } else {
        console.log("DEBUG-4")
        return (
            <p>docs Home Page</p>
        )
    }
}

export default docs
```

This is console Output:

```
[]
0
DEBUG-1
DEBUG-4
```

It displays "DEBUG-4" which is in else, but it does not display "docs Home Page" in the Browser.
Instead it shows 404

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your component name with capitalized word `Docs` . User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized. Read the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized